# What are the effects of populism on bushido?

Tags: civilization-5

Japan's **Bushido** power allows damaged units to fight at full strength. The **Populism** policy in the autocracy tree gives a 25% power boost to damaged units. Will these powers stack to make my wounded units stronger than ones at full health? If so, is there any way to intentionally damage my own units to take advantage of this?

Comment: This is an awesome idea, if it works!

Comment: Damaging units is not normally a problem... just attack with them. Either they'll win, or they'll get damaged and win next time!

Comment: Failing that, move into range of an enemy city for one turn. Be peppered with arrows / rocks for 1 damage. Voila!

Answer (score 10):

I just tried it out, and Bushido effectively cancels out Populism.  You get your normal strength, whether you are damaged or not, and you never get the 25% power boost.